# How do I manipulate my data in excel and create a funnel chart in excel with raw data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Candidate Table]

Is there a way I can create a funnel chart, split by gender using the data in the table attached. i.e. 6 candidates were new applicants, 6 candidates made it to recruiter screen, 5 candidates made it to first interview, 4 candidates made it to final interview and 2 candidates made it to offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to screenshots/ below:

**Regular funnel charts:**

```
=SUM(1*(FILTER(E$9:E$17,--($C$9:$C$17=$D19))>0))
```

[image: Regular]

---

**Inverted funnels**

**Labels/data**

```
=OFFSET($I$8,0,-COLUMNS($E21:E21)+1,1,1)


=SUM(1*(FILTER(INDEX($E$9:$I$17,0,MATCH(E$21,$E$8:$I$8,0))>0,--($C$9:$C$17=$D22))))
```

[image: Inverted chart data/labels]

---

**Graphs**

[image: Funnel charts for different methods/pesentatinonn]

---

**REVISED:**  *"How to have both genders showing on same funnel chart?"*

**Attempt 1** *HACK  (Bascially 2 graphs with some gradient shading tricks etc)*

[image: Hack]

**Attempt 2** - *nailed it ☺*

*Note - this simply requires making the one gender (female in this case) all 'negative', multiply by -1 the relevant values to plot...*

[image: Combo Box with Stacked Bar Graphs to create split funnel for M/F']

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9gvp_6umrRZeoPNfz_g?e=ZVFZn2)'s a read-only copy of the (macro-free) file, for convenience...

---

Comment: thanks this helps! However is there a way that the male and female data could be in the same funnel chart rather than separately? So that you can compare male and female numbers. So in your case 5 males and 4 females at the 1st stage, in the same funnel chart. Also I’m assuming we can still add the data labels to these graphs also?

Comment: For sure - do you want an overlay or different colours (what's the deal with different genders actually? How do you want them split or was the a red herring?)

Comment: So I would like the genders to be in different colours. For context, the reason for this is that I would like to see if there is a high percentage of a certain gender dropping out at a specific part of the hiring process. For example do a high percentage of females drop off at the 2nd stage....So if I have the male and female data in the same funnel, in different colours, its easier to compare. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: See the back at the end of my pvs soln - I'm not sue how to 'stack' funnels diagrams and see Excel conveniently makes the combo graph option go 'blank/unclickable' when the funnel displaying in first instance.... will have a litte tinker but this is as prob as good as I'm gonna get it in the time avail (was thinking sparklines, or column graphs in a combination with each on series (m/f) on diferent series and shown 'in reverse' for the one - which is not too hard (in theory at least! )

Comment: Ohh okay great. So just for clarity did you change the formula or did you just bring the two graphs together? I wasn’t quite sure how you imposed the graphs together.

Comment: See the latest version mate - haven't done this type of chart before so was good fun experimenting (and realising I need a life lol :)

Comment: (PPS - if you want to include numbers instead of percentages that's quick/easy to do - I actually had to 'add data values' (which shows the numbers, albeit negative values for females, then point this to a different range when you right click on the labels and select 'edit' / you'll see the option 'use range for data values' in the right panel that pops up for formatting etc. - if I've lost you / confused (I have that tendancy with self too ☺) let me know - else have a good d